# Access: trying to open a form and populate a textbox with the value from another form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Okay, I'm obviously doing something wrong, but can't figure out what it is, and this should be pretty simple.

I have a button on a form that opens another form and populates a textbox in the second form with a value from the first form.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub test_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "subfrm_EA_COMMENT_ADD"
Forms!subfrm_EA_COMMENT_ADD.txtUWI = Me.txtUWI
End Sub
```

This works just fine, however I want the form to open in a dialog window, so I modified the script to this:

```
Private Sub test_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "subfrm_EA_COMMENT_ADD", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acDialog
Forms!subfrm_EA_COMMENT_ADD.txtUWI = Me.txtUWI
End Sub
```

Now I am getting a run-time error 2450.

I've searched around regarding this error, but can't find any answers that work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I found you an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345831/ms-access-openform-acdialog-option-does-not-seem-to-work When using acDialog, any code after whats calling it doesnt execute until form is closed

Comment: You can use the `OpenArgs` parameter to pass things to a dialog form.

Comment: So what would be the best way around this problem?

Comment: Thanks, Erik. How would I structure this?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I ended up removing the acDialog. I'm not sure why Access has to make everything so blazing difficult sometimes. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around for this issue using a temp variable. I created a temp variable at the beginning of my Add Comment button, then set the unbound text box in the Comment dialog window to the value of the temp variable. This works like a charm and I can now open my windows in dialog instead of normal.

I just wanted to let others know in case they run into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

acDialog parameter causes code execution of first form to suspend until second form is closed.

Options for populating control on second form:

1. remove acDialog parameter and let first form set value on second form - this does defeat your intended goal of opening form in dialog mode, maybe just need to set PopUp and/or Modal property as Yes
2. pass data with OpenForm OpenArgs argument and code behind second form reads its own OpenArgs property
3. second form references first form control to grab value
4. first form sets a TempVar or global variable before opening second form and second form pulls from those

Option 2 is my preference:

```
Private Sub test_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "subfrm_EA_COMMENT_ADD", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acDialog, Me.txtUWI
End Sub
```

To read OpenArgs property, code behind second form, possibly in the Current event:

`If Me.NewRecord Then Me.txtUWI = Me.OpenArgs`