# Assign a variable based on user input from a different form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to have a user select data from a form and use this selection to assign to variables in VBA code related to another form.

I want a custom list box with a form but I need to get the selected value into a variable rather than into a form control because then I can do other things with it.

Code in Form1 run from a button.

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "Select Email Contact", acFormDS, , "[Matter Contacts].[Matter Number] =" & Matternumber, acFormReadOnly, windowmode:=acDialog
MsgBox ("Okay, please select the Client you want to send the file to")
EmailAddress = Forms![Select Email Contact]!Email
```

In Form2 (Select Email Contact) I created a form in datasheet view which lists Names and Email addresses based on a query. The query displays a list of names and email addresses.

Once I select an email address I want to assign that email address to a variable in the first form. In this case i have called it Email Address.

I can't stop the code from running in form1, while form2 is having the user select the data.
I thought that acDialog mode did this, but it doesn't.
I also tried putting in the above message box but this only means I cannot access the second form and as soon as I click ok the code on form1 starts running again.

Comment: add the property SelectedEmail to the database :)  To do this first add a code module to the database using the ribbon.  In the module add two public functions.  getSelectedEmail as string and setSelectedEmail(value).  have these functions set and get a private SelectedEmail.  Now you can set and get SelectedEmail from almost anywhere in Access and you can add any benefit of properties you want like validation and default values.  For bonus points put SelectedEmail in a table of settings to persist SelectedEmail when your database is closed.

Comment: [Select Email Contact] form should have the MsgBox code and set a global variable or TempVar with selected email address or use a cascading combobox or listbox on form 1.

Comment: Yes, acDialog does pause code execution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345831/ms-access-openform-acdialog-option-does-not-seem-to-work

Answer (score 1):

Common question, and common goal.

So, we are to pop/display a dialog form. Since this is a dialog form, then the calling code WAITS for that form to be closed. Once closed, then your code continues, but the problem is now that the pop form is closed, then how do you get the value "returned" from that form?

There are 2 ways.

One way is in the dialog form, you can set the selected value into a global variable, and then when user selects and closes the form, the calling code continues, and you can use the value of the global variable.

However, using global variable should be a LAST resort, since then to re-use that form, you not only copy the form, but have to "know" and "remember" the global variable also.

There is a second way, and this road I HIGHLY recommend, since it allows you to:

Pop a dialog form.

Return ANY value(s) from the form (calling code waits), and we do NOT need any global variables.

The "trick" for this approach is to "kick" the dialog form OUT of dialog mode, code continues, we get/grab values from the form (maybe even as you ask into some variables), AND THEN CLOSE that dialog form!!!

So, this trick is achieved by NOT closing the dialog form but setting its "visible" property to false.

This MEANS that:

If the user hits the "X" to close the form, OR HITS your cancel button?

WHEN the form been closed, we assume cancel.

However, if the user hits the "ok" button, then we assume valid selection.

Let's assume we have a form to display hotels.

But we want to pop a form to select the city from a list box (not the best example but this example will suffice for this goal).

So, our simple form - continuous form, and a button to pop that dialog form.

Say like this:

[image]

And then say we build what will become our "pop dialog" form, say this:

[image]

Ok, so we will pop the form, let user select value, and return/get the value from that pop form.

So, the code will look like this in the main form (pop filter button).

```
Private Sub cmdFilter_Click()

    Dim strF        As String
    Dim strCity     As String ' our varible to set form city selected
    
    strF = "frmCityAsk"
    DoCmd.OpenForm strF, , , , , acDialog
    
    If CurrentProject.AllForms(strF).IsLoaded = False Then
       ' form was closed, that means user canceled out
       Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' get this far, user made selection
    
    ' user did NOT cancel or close form (which = cancel)
    ' get any and all values we want from this form
    ' free to get as many values from any control as we wish
    ' in this example, we grab the listbox value (city selected)
       
    strCity = Forms(strF)!lstCity
    ' get more values, walk the dog, do whatever
    
    DoCmd.Close acForm, strF    ' don't forget to close the form!!!
       
       
    ' filter this form based on city selection
    
    Me.Filter = "City = '" & strCity & "'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
    Me.txtCity = strCity
    

End Sub
```

So, the "trick" here is if user closes form, (or hits our close button) in that pop dialog form, we assume cancel.

ONLY WHEN user hits "ok" do we assume valid selection.

So, now the code for the pop form. This approach IS MUCH better than using global variables - and we can return 1 or 10 values!!!!

So ok button code, and close button code:

```
Private Sub cmdOk_Click()

   ' user hit ok, kick form out of dialog mode
   ' calling code will continue
   
   Me.Visible = False
   
End Sub


Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()

   ' user hit close - just close the form
   
   DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
   
End Sub
```

So, the ok button sets form visible = false, THIS ALLOWS CALLING CODE to continue!!!!!

The effect is thus this:

[image]

so, the "ok" button in the pop form sets `Me.Visible = False`.

That kicks form out of dialog, and now our calling code can grab ANY value OF any control we want. We are free to shove those values into some variable, close the form, and now do whatever we want from the values we "grabbed" or saved from the pop dialog form.

What is rather nice as noted, we are free to grab one value, or 5 values from that form.

We not used global variables, and that form can now be popped by any code or any form - thus resulting in a re-useable pop form.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent summary, that makes perfect sense now and i it has helped massively, though i think i need a very short coding break before i set it into practice. One thing that isnt really answered anywhere but i think i just discovered.  The form that is being called does that need to be a single form, ie not in datasheet view? or does it not matter, because the code i was using seemed to open in datasheet view rather than single form and the code seemed to just keep runnning is this correct?Also as a side note (i am still learning this forum). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, you can freely pop a "continues items" form, and that will look, work and seem like a datasheet. Turns out that a long standing "issue" in access that a dialog form can't be a data sheet. But, as noted, you can easy make a continues items form to look much the same. And if you REALLY needed a datasheet, then build a main form + sub form as datasheet, and that form + sub form can be used or popped as a dialog form.  So, datasheets can't be launched as dialog, but every other type of form can be. No big deal to as noted create a multiple items form (continues form) anyway.

Comment: So, any form you pop as dialog? Yes, it can quite much be any kind of form (continues items for example). One exception is a datasheet form.  And the dialog form can even be a form with a child sub-form if you wish.  At the end of day , the trick is HOW to make the code wait (must be acDialog - not even modal forms halt calling code), and of course using me.visible = false to kick out of dialog mode and to allow calling code to continue.   At that point, you are free to get/grab/use/see/enjoy any values on that form, be it controls or even public variables declared in that dialog form.

Comment: Thanks, your explanations have made it perfectly clear now.  I am just fiddling with the forms and subforms like you suggested could be done.  One error which just came up is that it says i cant hide the form that has the focus.  Is this because you cant have a select button actually on the subform and they should be removed?

Comment: A button that has the focus can't be set visible = false, but a form and using me.visible is a mount Everest different issue. So, in a given form, (not a sub form), you can go me.visible = false.  However, if that form is nested as sub form, then you can't set me.visible = false - you have to do that in the parent form, and we ONLY ever doing this for a dialog form anyway.  If you were/are in the sub form, and you wanted to kick out of dialog, then you could go me.Parent.Visible = false.